# Wrong fstab cause to fail boot UBUNTU

Tags: boot, permissions, mount, fstab

after I accidentally commented my `uuid` in my `fstab` and now it fails to boot i only sees a terminal but i can login there like i normally do but no Ubuntu interface. I tried to remove the comment(#) but i cant because it only have a read permission. I'm trying to migrate from windows to Ubuntu for programming purposes so basically I'm a newbie. Can someone advise me what to do?

Comment: Before you edit the `fstab` type in `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` so that the partition goes into Read Write mode.

Comment: @Terrance That sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you boot to Recovery Mode, the root partition `/` goes into Read Only mode by default.  Before you can make any changes run the following line:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Or

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then when you are completed with your changes to your `/etc/fstab` file all you should have to do is reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where accidentally I added a letter at the beginning of my fstab file. My system booted into emergency mode. The text at the bottom of the screen read:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "sytemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenence
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and a new line appeared at the bottom that read:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~#
```

ubuntu-server was my system's hostname.

I typed in `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and was able to remove the letter. I saved my changes, exited nano, reboot my system, and it worked fine.